# Saving Excel Sheet with code as xlsm looses the code

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I'm creating Sheets dynamically, which works just fine. One of the created Sheets does contain VBA (Worksheet_Activate) which is inserted using VBA, also working perfectly.

Now I'm trying to save the created file, the while loop is used to force saving
I tried:

```
While Not workbookUsed.Saved


Dim filePath As String

filePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Excel File mit Makro (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")


    If VarType(filePath) = vbString Then

   workbookUsed.SaveAs _
            FileName:=filePath, _
            FileFormat:=52
  End If

Wend

End Sub
```

and i tried using

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
```

Method.

Both work and create an .xlsm file, with all the generated Contents in them, except for the VBA Code that is on the worksheets, it's just empty like a normal .xlsx file.

Interestingly if you stop the procedure after saving the file, and pushing ctrl+s Excel recognizes that something has changed and saves the whole workbook.

But if i close the workbook after that using

```
workbookUsed.Close
```

i get a file again, without VBA Code in it, even if i set it to not saving on close.

So is there any Special Parameter that has to be set, so that the whole workbook gets saved, including the vba Content?

Comment: Weird, what is the name of your sub? Have you tried to compile the VbaProject?

Comment: Actually, do you add code inside the Worksheet Object of the VbaProject in the same sub procedure that saves the file?

Comment: No, I've got a Main Sub  `Sub lcds () ` this contains `Set lcds_wb = Workbooks.Add` and calls all the Subs needed for creation of the sheet (About 40), the last thing Sub it calls, is the Sub which is Display above with the Name ` Sub saveFile ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the code that saves the file in a separate procedure called `SaveWorkbook` for example and use the following at the end of your main procedure:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2), "SaveWorkbook"
```

This will schedule the procedure that saves the file to run 2 sec later and would let Excel the time to process the changes to the VBproject before it can be saved.

Comment: Thank you, this would do, but has major drawbacks.

If i use the OnTime method, the whole script keeps running and the next Sub is getting executed. Which means i that my main method finishes and the the "SaveWorkbook" is run. Since the the "SaveWorkbook" is followed by an other Sub, this would force me to snake tail through all Subs that need to be excecuted after the save (ok can be done, but dirty), but it also means that i can't call the "workbookUsed" object anymore. 
Since Sleep and Wait are suspending Excel, those don't do the trick either. But now i know that i have to waiste time

Comment: @kai, another option would be to create the new workbook inside another Excel instance. See for example method 3 in this article: https://excelgorilla.com/excel/general/open-multiple-instances-excel/

Comment: I now changed over to write the safe Code into a new sheet in the workbook, which gets activated when the Code finishes (put a writing on it that the Programm finished) and put all actionhandlers to triggering the safe routine. The last line of the routine deletes this sheet. Not nice, but works and there can't be any issues with computing speed.